# How to check value in a loop?

Tags: python

I have a code to print the last line of a file (update real time) in a while loop. What I want to do is to check "data" is not the same as in the last loop, so that it won't print duplicated text. How do I achieve that?

I want to do something like this:

```
starttime = time.time()

while True:
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        last_line = lines[-1]
        if data is not last_line:
            data=last_line
    print(data)
    time.sleep(1 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1))
```

Comment: Start by defining `data` as an empty string outside of the while loop, so that it's state is 'preserved' between iterations.

Comment: Seems like you're following a log. If you are only concerned with the file growing, you can check the size of the file using the `stat` module and read only the newer portion of the file. You can `seek()` to the new part and read only the new parts.
Otherwise, your program will take an increasingly long time just to read the lines you already read before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo may defined `data` (renamed `last_data`) before the loop, then use the `print` inside the `if` statement. Also I'd suggest to read the file wuth a for loop, it avoid reading all file at once in memory

```
starttime = time.time()
last_data = None
while True:
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            last_line = line.rstrip()
        if last_data != last_line:
            last_data = last_line
            print(last_data)
    time.sleep(1 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the last value and check if it has changed. E.g.:

```py
check_every_seconds = 3
filename = 'test.txt'
last_value = None

def read_last_line_of_file(name):
    return open(name).read().splitlines()[-1]

while True:
    value = get_last_line_of_file(filename)
    if value != last_value:
        print(value)
        last_value = value
    time.sleep(check_every_seconds)
```